# AWS: Not able to delete Elasticsearch Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

At AWS console, Elasticsearch dashboard, I chose Actions -> Delete domain to delete Elasticsearch service.
But, the domain name still shows at the Elasticsearch dashboard even though the "Domain status" shows "Being deleted". . There are three network interfaces attached to the Elasticsearch service. I am not able to Detach and delete those network interfaces because of it. Please help.

Comment: Perhaps it takes a while to delete an Elasticsearch cluster/domain?

Comment: For more than two weeks, I have kept deleting it, i.e. I have deleted numerous times. But, it is useless. Elasticsearch cluster/domain remains at the dashboard showing "Being deleted".

Comment: You didn't mention the timescale earlier. At this point, I suggest that you raise a support ticket with AWS.

Comment: Patience is a virtue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar situation with the AWS console being stuck at "Being deleted". When I tried with the CLI, the delete completed in less than a minute. That leads me to believe the cluster was already deleted but the UI was stuck. The command I ran was:

```
aws es delete-elasticsearch-domain --domain-name my-domain
```